# Facebook Sharer for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sharer

I searched about Facebook Like/Recommand/Share function for iOS for many many days. Today I finally come [here](http://blog.betterthantomorrow.com/2010/12/11/mobile-sharer-now-on-app-store/img_1361/comment-page-1/#comment-404) to find what I need. So I doubt How to do this? For Facebook Developers Website's documents are not detail, especially on iOS. So I am asking questions here. Thank you very much.

The image is [here](http://blog.betterthantomorrow.com/2010/12/11/mobile-sharer-now-on-app-store/img_1361/comment-page-1/#comment-404).

Comment: The Facebook Developer website has lots of detail. If you can be more specific you're likely to get a better response.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has an iOS SDK - check [**here**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) and [**here**](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). Maybe this could help you...

You could also provide backend support for FB likes etc. using oAuth Flow. For that you could use Python, PHP or any other popular language to interface with [**FB Graph API**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanna try [BMSocialShare](https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare).

Answer (score 0):

I try new facebook sharer dialog. You can find that [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

But first of all, you must open a facebook app. I set facebook app type to mobil internet instead of ios.

Secondly you can use this code for sharing :

```
  NSURL *shareURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=458358780877780&
link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/& 
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
caption=Reference%20Documentation&
description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/"]

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: shareURL];
```

You have to change your app_id within this shareURL.

Lastly; i give same redirect uri for both facebook api and direct url.